# How to get count of id's of one table from another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a database project on Voting where there is a candidate table and a cast_vote table . The can_id is a pk of candidate table and fk of cast_vote table . I want to know how many times the can_id was inserted in cast_vote and then I can show the candidates name and total vote .

I want the output to be like:
Name Aff_party Total_vote(cast_vote)

```
 select candidate.name
  2  count(cast_vote.can_id) as t_v
  3  from candidate
  4  left join cast_vote on candidate.can_id=cast_vote.can_id
  5  ;

create table voter(
    voter_id number(8),
    full_name varchar(20),
    gender varchar(7),
    seat_no number(5),
    age number(3) check (age>=18),
    primary key (voter_id)
);

create table candidate(
    can_id number(8),
    name varchar(256),
    age number(3) check (age>=18),
    gender varchar(7),
    aff_party varchar(256),
    seat_no number(5),
    seat_name varchar(256),
    net_income number(8),
    primary key(can_id)
);

create table cast_vote(
    vote_no number(15) not null,
    voter_id number(8) not null unique,
    can_id number(8),
    primary key(vote_no),
    foreign key (voter_id) references voter(voter_id),
    foreign key(can_id) references candidate(can_id)
);
```

Comment: table `voter` is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the GROUP BY clause. You need to add both can_id and candidate_name in the group by clause considering Multiple candidate can have the same name.

Try this-

```
SELECT C.can_id,
C.name,
COUNT(CV.can_id) AS t_v
FROM candidate C
LEFT JOIN cast_vote CV on C.can_id=CV.can_id
GROUP BY C.can_id,C.name
```

Comment: Doesn't workERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: "C"."CANDIDATE"."NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: Can you check now? One additional table name was there in the script. I have updated. the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY`.  Assuming you have no duplicate candidate names:

```
SELECT c.name, c.aff_party, COUNT(cv.can_id) as t_v
FROM candidate c LEFT JOIN
     cast_vote cv
     ON c.can_id = cv.can_id
GROUP BY c.name, c.aff_party;
```

If you can have duplicate candidate names, then you will want to distinguish them by their ids:

```
SELECT c.can_id, c.name, c.aff_party,
       COUNT(cv.can_id) as t_v
FROM candidate c LEFT JOIN
     cast_vote cv
     ON c.can_id = cv.can_id
GROUP BY c.can_id, c.name, c.aff_party;
```

Note that every unaggregated column in the `SELECT` is also in the `GROUP BY`.